# Xcode build error after project name change

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/matt/Documents/Xcode/GraphicalSet/GraphicalSet/SetTests/GraphicalSetTests/GraphicalSetTests.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

I tried adding a removing the GraphicalSetTests.m file from compile sources in build phases but to no avail.

There are two extra folders in that path: SetTests/GraphicalSetTests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your ProjectTests - > Build Phases ->  Compile Sources 
Remove this file ProjectTests.m and try to build again.

Comment: Yes that works, I did this before I saw your post though. Remove the file without readding it.